# alttemplate shows the default template id instead of redirected template

Tags: xslt, umbraco, xslt-1.0

I have a default desktop template **Home**. Using alttemplate I am redirecting the user to **mobileHome** template when the user request from mobile. Now when I use

```
<xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/@template"/>
```

in an XSLT which is used inside **mobileHome** the template id of **Home** is displayed instead of **mobileHome**. I need to take the template id of mobileHome(the redirected page). Any idea or solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We can't find the bugs in your code without seeing your code.

Comment: @Michael Kay Thanks for your response. Do you really need code. I am not doing anything complex. I have 2 template one for desktop and one for mobile. Desktop template is loaded initially. Using useragent I am redirecting the user to mobile template. Now <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/@template"/> displays the default template id. It is not showing the redirected template id. Please let me know if you still need code.

Comment: Yes, I can't help you without code. You are doing something wrong, and I can't tell what it is without seeing what you are doing. Apart from anything else, I don't understand what you mean by "redirecting a user to a template".

Comment: @MichaelKay, that's because this xslt problem is specific to Umbraco. You'd have to have some understanding of how Umbraco works in order to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The template property on your page will always return the id of the template that you have selected to use for the node in the backend. To determine if an alttemplate is being used, you can do something like the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetHttpItem('altTemplate')" />
```

See the following Our Umbraco forom posts for details:

- [Find the AltTemplate in use](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/7719-Find-the-AltTemplate-in-use)
- [Macro/xslt - rendering depending on used template](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/8672-Macroxslt---rendering-depending-on-used-template)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetHttpItem('altTemplate')" /> is not displaying anything.

Comment: Hmm... it might be case sensitive. Try `alttemplate` perhaps?